# WCF answer processing C#

Tags: c#, json, wcf, client

There is a WCF service and I need to use it`s method.

method takes 3 parameters - string, DateTime, DateTime.

## So my code is like this:

```
ServiceReference.LogsServiceClient myclient;
myclient = new ServiceReference.LogsServiceClient();
var response = myclient.GetHotPeriodLogs("somestring", dtFrom, dtTo);
```

========

Returned data type of method is some array (ServiceReference.TechLog[])

It seems the answer is the array of json responses.

So, I have the exception "Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1"

I should like to ask, what is the method to work with the answer?
Further, I need to insert each string of data into MSSQL DB, so I need to get sets of data. So, what I have to do?

Comment: So your method is supposed to return an array, but your response is in JSON. You need to convert it somehow using a library like Newtonsoft. Or just parse the JSON yourself.

Comment: Any example with newtonsoft?

Comment: Can you flesh out your code a bit more? Are you returning response in a method that expects an array? What is the method signature?

Comment: Method takes 3 parameters - string, datetime, datetime and returns an array ServiceReference.TechLog[] This one is the object, declared within WCF service. In object explorer I can see it's fields. Service is not on my side, so I can not see it's code.

Comment: Is this a method that you are trying to write, or one written by WCF? If you are writing it, why are you trying to return a ServiceReference.TechLog[]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. at first let us assume this is your `ServiceReference.TechLog` object:

```
public class TechLog
{
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
}
```

now we need a json deserilzer method like this:

```
public static T JsonDeserializer<T>(string jsonString)
{
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { DateFormatHandling=DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat };
    var instance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString, settings);
    return instance;
}
```

that's all we need. now we can deserilze any thing like this:

```
    var x = JsonDeserializer<TechLog[]>(response);
```

Comment: @ОлегСидоров I'm glad i could help you. please mark it as a answer so it closed.